# Issue with Soft keyboard, wanted to show an Edit text full view

Tags: android, layout, android-softkeyboard

I am sure this is not a duplicate question.

When I touch my edit text, android O.S. makes the Soft keyboard visible.

So that my editText lied just above the keyboard.  This is usual.

But I have button in that activity which has the property as

```
<button
  android:alignParentBottom : "true"
  ...
/>
```

And finally this button hides the half view of my edit text.

What I have already tried is :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode : "adjustPan | adjustResize"
```

with fullscreen and also not with fullscreen.

None of these works fine.

Again please consider I am damn sure that this issue arises because of the button with the 
`android:alignParentBottom : "true"` property.  But I am not supposed to  edit or remove  this button and its property.

Correct form should be the `**EditText**` must be lied up to the button and this `**button**` must be lied up to the **soft keyboard**, whenever this Soft keyboard is visible.

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you tried setting layout_above="buttonid" for edittext in layout

Comment: Is your parent LinearLayout ?

Comment: There are lots of textViews and other buttons available between this bottom button.  So I cannot set layout_above for edittext. @Arju

Comment: My parent Layout is Relative layout.  @Hasham

Comment: that is ok , it will alwyas be above the button

Comment: But not when the keyboard is visible..

Comment: The button lying on the edit text.. Hides half of the Edit text view.@Arju

Answer (score 0):

Change themes in android manifest file.

Comment: Tried no use. I guess no problem with themes.